# Vue 2 Component Mounts on One Page, Throws TypeError on another but works if loaded on first page before

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, components

I have a popup component which renders a photo ID that works currently on one page and I am trying to also have the component visible on another page. When I add my component to another page it throws an error at me. Unsure what is causing the error. Stack suggests my cleanup function doesn't exist, it is a function written in the component.

If however I load the photoID popup from the page which already has the working component and then navigate to the second page and try to open the new component it will load fine until I refresh the page.

My Popup component

```js
//popup.vue
<template>
<!--
  Rendering of this component should be handled by the parent using a v-if.
  Listen for event 'closeButtonPressed' to know when to stop rendering it.
-->
<div class="modal is-active">
  <div class="modal-background" @click="$emit('closeButtonPressed')"></div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p class="image is-4by3">
      <img class="photo-id-img" :src="photoIdObjectUrl">
    </p>
  </div>
  <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close" @click="$emit('closeButtonPressed')"></button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';
import utils from "../Utils/utils.js";

export default {
  name: 'photoIdPopup',
  props: {
    clientId: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    /**
     * This is a url we generate that points to a blob containing our photo
     * id image. An img element's src attribute can be set to it to
     * display the image.
     */
    photoIdObjectUrl: null,
  }),
  destroyed() {
    this.cleanUp();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      getFile: "filestorage/getFile",
    }),
    async getPhotoIdObjectUrl() {
      // Get photo id file from api.
      const file = await this.getFile({
        usercode: this.photoIdFile.usercode,
        id: this.photoIdFile.id,
        clientId: this.clientId,
      });
      // Convert the file to a blob.
      const blob = new Blob([utils.str2bytes(file)]);
      // Create a objectUrl from the blob for img element's src attribute.
      return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    },
    /** We have to cleanup the object urls we previously allocated. */
    cleanUp() {
      if (this.photoIdObjectUrl) {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.photoIdObjectUrl);
        this.photoIdObjectUrl = null;
      }
    },
    async initializePhotoIdImage() {
      this.photoIdObjectUrl = await this.getPhotoIdObjectUrl();
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      photoIdFile(state) {
        return state.filestorage['drLicense']; 
      }
    }),
  },
  watch: {
    photoIdFile: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(newPhotoIdFile) {
        if (newPhotoIdFile) {
          this.initializePhotoIdImage();
        } else {
          this.cleanup();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.photo-id-img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
</style>
```

How I'm calling the object on the new page, there is no difference in how I do it between this page and the page which has my working component.

```js
//interview-summary.vue

<photoIdPopup
    v-if="isPhotoIdShowing"  
    @closeButtonPressed="viewPhotoIdPressed"
    :clientId="clientId"
/>

viewPhotoIdPressed() {
   this.isPhotoIdShowing = !this.isPhotoIdShowing
```

Error Stack
[image: error stack]

Any help would be appreciated as I'm still learning Vue. My first assumption is that I'm missing an object in my state that I need to render the component properly but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your method is named `cleanUp` but you are calling it like `this.cleanup()`. Incorrect case.

Comment: @DecadeMoon Thank you. After fixing the typo I don't get an error anymore but I still can't get the photoID to load unless I load it on the original page first.